# How to determine if a gate/inverter can drive a fanout of 4 gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, spice, gate-driving

I have a circuit in which a driving inverter output (Fanout of 4) with equal Wn Wp sizing (m=4) is driving 4 other gates having same equal Wn Wp sizing (m=1). How to calculate if the inverter fanout is too much?

What if I connect 4 more gates to the output of the driving inverter output? How can I detect too-high fanout based on some formula calculation?

This is the driving inverter sizing in spice format:

```
SUBCKT inv4_1x1 a pa_vss vdd z
*.PININFO a:I pa_vss:I vdd:I z:O
MMN1 z a pa_vss pa_vss n W=68n L=20n m=4
MMP1 z a vdd vdd p W=68n L=20n m=4
.ENDS
```

What if its driving more than 4 inverters or other gates which look like this:

```
SUBCKT inv1_1x1 a pa_vss vdd z
*.PININFO a:I pa_vss:I vdd:I z:O
MMN1 z a pa_vss pa_vss n W=68n L=20n m=1
MMP1 z a vdd vdd p W=68n L=20n m=1
.ENDS
```

How can I compute if the Fanout of the driving inverter is too much from the spice netlist?

Comment: Welcome! Not an answer to your question but it’s not as easy as specified for fan-out of 4 and you connect 5 and it won’t work at all. It’s model dependent and down to your timing requirements. But if you are on the edge and 5 is just one too many, then yes, it would be possible from the netlist alone.